# In Ndepend dependency matrix, how can I hide some row assemblies?

Tags: matrix, dependencies, ndepend

I'd like to hide **some** of the row assemblies in my dependency matrix so that I can spot quickly the dependencies between assemblies of my project and a subset of 3rd party assemblies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible actions:

- First you write a [code query over LINQ (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) to select assemblies you wish to see in the matrix
- Second you export the list to the matrix headers (horizontal and vertical)

[image: Export code query result to matrix]

You can also hold Ctrl or Tab key + mouse click to select a sub-set of code element sin a matrix header, the same way you'd do with selecting files in Windows Explorer.

[image: Matrix and Ctrl or Tab keys]

These filtering actions can also be done if matrix headers are populated with namespaces, types, methods or fields.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, these mouse filtering actions are both very helpful and difficult to find (at least for me)!

Comment: Indeed, do you have suggestion to make this featurette more discoverable?

Comment: Finally, I find the feature good :). I think I was disturbed by the great number of colors used: white+purple for unselected rows, light+dark pink and orange when mouse hangs over, blue when clicking, light + dark yellow for application assemblies. So 9 colors with different uses. My suggestion would be: try to avoid the use of colors only for emphasizing rows; use discrete borders instead. Hope it helps. BTW, NDepend is great.